# FreeBSD, gmirror, hosed disklabel, or something

Tags: raid, freebsd, ufs

Okay so, here is my situation:

I had a gmirror instance set up for two 2TB drives, ad4 and ad6.

Yesterday, my system decided to refuse to reboot, complaining about a problem with ad4. The drive seemed to be spinning up then spinning down repeatedly. I assumed it was dead, and shut down the server and removed it. I went to RMA it, (It's only 7~ months old), and the seagate website required a code from having SeaTools analyze the drive to ensure it was faulty before RMAing. So I plugged it into my windows machine to run SeaTools. SeaTools crashed on me, repeatedly, and after researching the error, the only solution I could find dealt with reformatting the drive NTFS and then running SeaTools. So I did, and went "huh" when the format completed. I ran SeaTools, and it marked the drive as fine.

I decided it must have been a loose power cable, or a problem elsewhere in my server, so I decided I'd put the drive back in, let gmirror rebuild the array, and start looking for what caused the issue elsewhere. So I did. About 5 minutes after booting, I ran gmirror status, and to my horror saw "device ad6 DEGRADED, rebuilding." Realizing that gmirror was mirroring the NTFS partition to the drive with all my data, I turned off the machine, and pulled the drive. I unloaded gmirror, and went to try and mount the partition with all my data (ad6s1d), but it was gone. ad6 is there, as it the slice, ad6s1, but the partition is nowhere to be found.

I ran disklabel -w /dev/ad6 to re-write the disk label, and now I'm sitting here with scan_ffs running in a desperate attempt to retrieve that partition, and any of the data I can, which I hope will be the majority of it since gmirror only had time to mirror 1% of the 2TB drive, of which 800GB~ was used.

I'm looking for any advice whatsoever on how to go about getting my partition back.

Also, when I formatted the other member of the array NTFS, I did a quick format, so I assume the data is still on that drive too, though I have no clue at all how to get at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this on my own with the following steps:

1. Delete/Destroy the ad6s1 slice with gpart.
2. Delete/Destroy the ad6 geom with gpart.
3. Re-create both the geom, and then the slice.
4. Edit the disklabel and add the parition back.
5. Mount.

The partition is mounted and all my files seem to be intact, however, `fsck` is complaining rather loudly about soft updates, but the problem seems to have been resolved.